# creating php array from a table in mysql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

there. I'm migrating from mysql to PDO structure, and i had an issue when tryign a foreach statement, if i could get some help, would appreciate. the structure that doesn't work is:

```
foreach ($con -> query('SELECT MIN(LEAST(L1_RMS, L2_RMS, L3_RMS)) AS menor_valor FROM afunda_eleva') as $array_min_afund)
{
$intensidade_elevacao[] = $array_min_afund['menor_valor'];
}
```

where

$con is my variable to connect to the database. (working fine).

The error that i get when i run this is:

"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

The problem is that i've used this same structure some lines beyond this in the program and it worked. Does anyone know a possible reason for this to be happening? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

```
$result = ($con -> query('SELECT MIN(LEAST(L1_RMS, L2_RMS, L3_RMS)) AS menor_valor FROM afunda_eleva'));
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
    {
    $intensidade_elevacao[] = $row['menor_valor'];
    }
```

Comment: PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure. <- your query failed and you're trying to loop over a boolean false?

Comment: i don't think it's the query. Well, at least, it works on phpmyadmin.

Comment: `foreach()` loops through arrays, `$con->query()` is not returning an array so...

Comment: @Havenard "A nice feature of PDO::query() is that it enables you to iterate over the rowset returned by a successfully executed SELECT statement." - Which means the query result is either empty or a failure.

Comment: hmm, really. Now i got my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you'd bother looping, there's only going to be one record

Answer (score 0):

Something you're going to want to do is get PDO to throw exceptions. They're much harder to miss than warnings and errors.

Here's the PDO constructor I use...

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Now, assuming your query actually works, it's only going to return one row with one column so try the following

```
$stmt = $con->query('SELECT MIN(LEAST(L1_RMS, L2_RMS, L3_RMS)) AS menor_valor FROM afunda_eleva');
$menor_valor = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```